# LDAP server configuration: olcIdleTimeout and olcLogFile

Tags: configuration, openldap

I`ve setup a LDAP server. I`ve set the **olcIdleTimeout** property to 5 (seconds) for the purpose of testing and the **olcLogFile** to /var/log/slapd.log. Then I restarted the slapd service. So the entries look like this:

```
olcIdleTimeout: 5 
olcLogFile: /var/log/slapd.log
```

Is there a reason this changes arent aplied? The log file is empty (i created it manually, because I have read somewhere that it must be created before you write to it) and nothing happens on the page after 5 seconds.

:-/

Answer (score 0):

The olcXXX properties are for online configuration. So you didn't need to restart slapd at all. It is sounding as though you put online configuration directives into slapd.conf. They won't work in there. Remove the 'olc' part.

Comment: No, I put the directives in the 'cn=config.ldif' file.

Comment: @RunoTheDog So you are doing offline changes to your online configuration? And do you start slapd *without* the -f option?

Comment: Yes, I am starting it without the -f option. What do you mean offline changes? The ldap server is running while I edit the config file and the changes aren`t being applied. What would the page look after the idletimeout would run out?

Comment: @RunoTheDog Modifying configuration files is an offline change. You can and probably should do that while the server was running, via an LDAP browser. I have no idea what you mean by 'the page' or 'how the page would look'.

Answer (score 0):

olcLogFile is only used on Windows because it lacks syslog.

check this for more information

https://serverfault.com/questions/324608/how-do-i-get-openldap-on-centos-6-to-write-anything-to-its-log-files